# How to define &mut [u8] in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to call [`openssl::sign::Signer::sign`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/sign/struct.Signer.html#method.sign), which has the signature:

```
pub fn sign(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, ErrorStack>
```

I'm trying to hand over `buf`. How to I make it `&mut [u8]`?

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }
```

**src/main.rs**

```rust
use openssl::{base64, sign::Signer};

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = [];
    let str = base64::encode_block(signer.sign(&mut buffer));
}
```

But get an error:

```
openssl::base64::encode_block(signer.sign(&mut buffer));
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&[u8]`, found enum `std::result::Result`
```

Comment: `sign` doesn't return the modified `buffer`, it modifies `buffer` over buffer's mutable reference, `signer.sign(&mut buffer);//handle result in this line` then use it like this `let encoded_str= openssl::base64::encode_block(&buffer);`

Comment: Could you tell us how `Signer` is created? It's currently not included in the post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. The code that you have here does not reproduce the error you have shown, as you instead get a different error due to `signer` not existing in your code. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f57047b87b9e522bcf0ea4979305551c))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this crate, but [`base64::encode_block`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/base64/fn.encode_block.html) expects `&[u8]`, while the return value of [`Signer::sign`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/sign/struct.Signer.html#method.sign) is a `Result` that returns the *number of bytes written* as `usize`.

I'm not sure if the *number of bytes written* is what you want to encode?

If you want to encode `buffer` to `base64`, you could do:

```rust
use openssl;

fn main() {
   let mut buf = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111];
   let encoded = openssl::base64::encode_block(&buf);

   println!("{}", encoded);
}
```

That should give you:

```sh
aGVsbG8=
```

Which is `hello` as `base64`.

Or, as an example, if you want to `sign` the given `buf` and encode that as `base64`:

```rust
use openssl::{base64, hash::MessageDigest, pkey::PKey, rsa::Rsa, sign::Signer};

fn main() {
    let keypair = Rsa::generate(2048).unwrap();
    let keypair = PKey::from_rsa(keypair).unwrap();
    let signer = Signer::new(MessageDigest::sha256(), &keypair).unwrap();

    let mut buf = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111].repeat(52);

    let written = signer.sign(&mut buf).unwrap();
    println!("bytes written: {}", written);

    let encoded = base64::encode_block(&buf);
    println!("base64: {}", encoded);
}
```

Which returns:

```sh
bytes written: 256
base64: wB4lBbyzpfRPInxhwm0XVKI3dQYqcUZWNdKyb4RTGDUmwq1DDDbQjMRmFBobRse3pNOxoMy+QQNSXsgI46b75hPfkar9TUowrIGk4Y+ZWWX/cwNJCJazC1dfanP4uft0fzpYJKMSfJTAxswccu1g4yT+u0V5yq+eHbeGDJ+bF2MMhCPds7wGjJguxO0e4wx+HQdVGbU9jrHQ38oIYTChG92iKLRpciiyB8vrbNEBcNNi4hlw6U0sUdz6scpXceREdPFVA6wr0otY3wSZLfcIeKELoBQkR2KPNTTCROreVJ49tXwiQdGe7Ky0NDeNba2H5tKu3uLAtAiG/hVoKEAJG2VsbG8=
```

Comment: Thanks, and my apologies for totally noob.I feel understand how to question at this website.I solved this problem by your help!

Comment: @Nick, I'm glad you managed to solve it! Have a great day.